# It is not creating folder ??Cant Find out the error?

Tags: angular

ng g c header

ng : File C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information,
see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ng g c header
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

It should create a folder header

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell or cmd in administrative mode and run the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

or try this command in terminal(Visual Studio Code terminal or any IDE you are using)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```